# Use a js function after another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="panel" id="home">
  <video id='video1' width='630' autoplay controls>
    <source id="source1" src="1_uno.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

I' ve this js function that at the and of 'video1' makes the refresh of div home putting 3 buttons

```
var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1");
myVideo.addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
function myHandler(e) {
  document.getElementById('home').innerHTML = '<button type="button" style="height: 180px; width: 200px"  onclick="refreshdiv("a")"> a </button><button type="button" style="height: 180px; width: 200px" onclick="refreshdiv("b")"> b </button><button type="button" style="height: 170px; width: 200px" onclick="refreshdiv("c")"> c </button>';
}
```

Until this part everything works good, now as u can see onclick event i do refreshdiv function:

```
function refreshdiv(str) {
  if(str=='a'){
    src='1_uno.mp4';
  }
  if(str=='b'){
    src='2_due.mp4';
  }
  if(str=='c'){
    src='3_tre.mp4';
  }
  document.getElementById('home').innerHTML = '<video id="video1" width="630" autoplay controls><source id="source1" src="'+ src +'" type="video/mp4"></video>';
}
```

The problem is when I click on the buttons anything happens and in Chrome i got this error: `Unexpected token }`

All the function are inside: `<script></script>`

Comment: At the very least you have a problem with quotes in your onclick attributes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change 
`onclick="refreshdiv("a")">` to  `onclick="refreshdiv(\'a\')">` etc.

```
'<button type="button" style="height: 180px; width: 200px"  onclick="refreshdiv(\'a\')"> a </button><button type="button" style="height: 180px; width: 200px" onclick="refreshdiv(\'b\')"> b </button><button type="button" style="height: 170px; width: 200px" onclick="refreshdiv(\'c\')"> c </button>';
```

Here's wroking example
http://jsfiddle.net/8RjW5/1/

Comment: @user3658308 if you are asking about "escaping" a string, then there are tutorials about it on the net. If you are asking why single quotes and not double quotes - i'm trying to find out now.

Comment: I asked a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24458532/escaping-double-quotes-around-argument-of-onclick-in-single-quote-string

Answer (score 2):

You should change `onclick="refreshdiv("a")"` to `onclick="refreshdiv(\'a\')"` in your `<button>` tags. The "inner" double quote is actually ending the "outer", an alternative would be to escape the inner quotes like so: `\"`.

Comment: But all of this is in a string that is enclosed in `'`, so you can't use `'` either, and need to escape.

Comment: You are of course correct @jcaron, I have updated my answer accordingly.