# Escaping double quotes around argument of onClick in single quote string

Tags: javascript, escaping

I'm asking about escaping such string:

```
function my(mstr){alert(mstr);};
document.getElementById('home').innerHTML = '<button onclick="my("a")">a</button>'
```

We have 
`'<... onclick="fun("a")"...>'` 
 so its double quotes inside of double quotes inside of single quotes.

Simple `'<button onclick="my(\"a\")">...'` gives syntax error.
 I know that i could escape it like 
`'<button onclick="my(\'a\')">...'`

but i wonder why this syntax error appears.

EDIT: here's jsfiddle for it http://jsfiddle.net/pVy9W/1/

EDIT2: BallBin said it renders `<button onclick="my("a")">a</button>` so  
trying to escape  backslash:
`'<button type="button" onclick="my(\\\"a\\\")">a</button>';`
it renders as strange:
`<button type="button" onclick="my(\" a\")"="">a</button>`
and   gives error:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

Comment: A better approach would be to not inline event handlers in the first place. Use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) instead.

Comment: What is the actual error you get?

Comment: @merlin2011 `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }` in google chrome and just syntax error in FF

Comment: Because when it renders the button it renders it as `<button onclick="my("a")">a</button>`.  You need the mix of double and single quotes.

Comment: @MattBurland its not much of my code, its from someone asking here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24457630/use-a-js-function-after-another-function/24457690

Comment: @Ballbin ok, how would you go about escaping it?

Comment: @Chris The problem is that you can't use double quotes there; your script is causing invalid HTML output. In this case you absolutely have to use single quotes inside the double quotes.  Your other option would be to define your function call as a string variable like `var functionCall = "my(\"a\")";` and then use `document.getElementById('home').innerHTML = '<button onclick=" + functionCall + ">a</button>";`.

Comment: @Chris like how you have it in the 3rd example `onclick="my(\'a\')"`. Which renders it as `<button onlcick="my('a')">a</button>`. Now it when the button is clicked it will call `my()` passing in the character 'a'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double quotes inside HTML attribute values that are delimited by double quotes should be represented as `&quot;` The `\` character has no special significance in HTML.

Your JavaScript string is delimited with `'` characters so `"` do not need escaping (with `\`) for JavaScript.

---

I'd avoid nesting JS inside HTML inside JS in the first place though. Use DOM instead of string manipulation.

```
// Create button with content and an event handler
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.appendChild(document.createTextNode('a'));
button.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);

// Get container, empty it and add the button to it
var container = document.getElementById('home');
container.innerHTML = ''; // Delete all nodes inside the element
container.appendChild(button);

function clickHandler(event) {
    my("a");
}
```